# Derivative of $\lVert Ax-y \rVert _{2}^{2l}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, partial-derivative, compression

$A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix, $x$ is a $n \times 1$ vector, $y$ is an $m \times 1$ vector. Is this solution true?

Solution:

Let

$$
f\left( x \right) = \left( Ax-y \right) ^T\left( Ax-y \right) ,
$$

we have

$$
\nabla \left[ f\left( x \right) \right] ^l=l\left[ f\left( x \right) \right] ^{l-1}\nabla f\left( x \right) =2l\left[ \left( Ax-y \right) ^T\left( Ax-y \right) \right] ^{l-1}A^T\left( Ax-y \right).
$$

Comment: I think you're missing a factor of $2$: $\nabla f(x)=2A^T(Ax-y)$.

Comment: Yes, thank you.